# Parse nestes JSON with Restofit

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I want to ask about parsing complex structure in **Retrofit**. I have JSON from my REST:

```
{
  "persons" : [ {
    "name" : "Ivan",
    "age" : 24,
    "address" : {
      "country" : "Russia",
      "city" : "Moscow"
    },
    "birthDate" : "1992-02-07T00:00:00"
  }, {
    "name" : "Katarina",
    "age" : 27,
    "address" : {
      "country" : "Russia",
      "city" : "Petersburg"
    },
    "birthDate" : "1989-08-15T00:00:00"
  }
],
"amount": 2
}
```

And I'm wondering how can I capture this to my POJOs. I've got 3 classes:

```
public class Persons {

    private Person[] persons;
    private int amount;
    ... getters, setters...
}

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Address address;
    private Date birthDate;
    ...
}

public class Address {

    private String country;
    private String city;

    ...
}
```

I tried to call my GET method by returning Call, but it doesn't work, only **amount** works fine, my array of persons is null.

How can I parse that?

Comment: What is **Restofit**? Never heard about it. Provide any links

Comment: @Andremoniy My bad, sorry.

Comment: What type of converter do you use?

Comment: I'm using GsonConverter instance from factory.

Comment: Hey, @KurdTt, never do so: never correct mistakes in your code in answer if they were mentioned in answer, this cause to answer be useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Persons {

    private Person[] persons;

    public Person[] getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Person[] persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    private int amount;
}

class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.birthDate = format.parse(birthDate.replace("T"," "));
            System.out.println("brith");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int age;
    private Address address;
    private Date birthDate;
}

class Address {

    private String country;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    private String city;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using List of persons instead of array:

```
public class Persons {

    private List<Person> persons;
    private int amount;
    ... getters, setters...
}
```

Comment: Do you have getter-setters for Person Class?

Comment: I've got getter-setters for every object in my class, so, in this case, I've got g/s for List of persons and amount, in persone I've got for every field, etc.